# Cannot declare class error in Symfony 4 custom bundle

Tags: php, symfony4

I keep getting this error as I try to create a new reusable bundle in Symfony 4.

```
Compile Error: Cannot declare class App\ICatcher\Builder\ControlPanel, because the name is already in use
 (1/1) FatalErrorException Compile Error: Cannot declare class App\ICatcher\Builder\ControlPanel, because the name is already in use in ControlPanel.php line 23
```

ControlPanel.php:

```
namespace App\ICatcher\Builder;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
class ControlPanel extends Response {    
    public function index(){
        return new Response(
            '<html><body>TEST! BUNDLE!!</body></html>'
        );
    }    
}
```

Main bundle file:

```
namespace App\ICatcher\Builder;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class Builder extends Bundle
{
}
```

Composer:

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/",
            "App\\ICatcher\\Builder\\":"src/ICatcher/Builder/src"
        }
    },
```

bundles:

```
return [
    [...]  
    App\ICatcher\Builder\Builder::class => ['dev' => true,'test' => true],
];
```

UPD1: 
When I comment the whole ControlPanel class out, refresh the page - the error disappears and does not reappear when I uncomment it again - it runs the class and shows text in Response. Then if I run composer update - it fails with the same error and if I refresh the page after that - it fails with the same error again.

Comment: `because the name is already in use in ControlPanel.php line 23` please show the whole file then :)

Comment: Sorry, I have condensed the file for the post (removed comments and empty lines) - line 23 is the end of the file (the last curvy bracket).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove from composer.json line `"App\\ICatcher\\Builder\\":"src/ICatcher/Builder/src"`, because in your case namespace is duplicated when you dump `vendor/autoload.php` by `composer update` command.